# Android OpenGL some Texture not loading/reloading

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I seem to have a bit of a strange problem, on one phone two textures dont load up at all as they appear as white rectangles, however, they both load on my phone. Another issue is that upon resuming the game a loading screen shows, this works great the first time the app is paused, but after a second resume the texture doesnt load on my phone...however the textures that the loading screen is loading all appear fine.

All textures are by a power of 2 and are 024x1024...there are around 20 textures in total.

What reasons could there be for the type of issue?

Here is the code for reloading...

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {         
        super.onSurfaceCreated(gl, config);
        if(firstTimeCreate) {
            load();            //load settings
            Assets.Load(this);
            firstTimeCreate = false;            
        } else {
            //When screen is resumed....
            Assets.ReloadLoadingScreen();
        }
```

That is where everything is this is the load method...

```
GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
        int[] textureIds = new int[1];
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textureIds, 0);
        textureId = textureIds[0];

        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = fileIO.readAsset(fileName);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
            setFilters(GL10.GL_LINEAR , GL10.GL_LINEAR);         
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
            width = bitmap.getWidth();
            height = bitmap.getHeight();
            bitmap.recycle();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load texture '" + fileName +"'", e);
        } finally {
            if(in != null)
                try { in.close(); } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
```

and the bind method...

```
public void bind() {
GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
}
```

Dont think anything is wrong with the above but maybe there is?

Answer (score 0):

I think we would need some more details to properly point you in the right direction. Unfortunately, there are so many things that could be causing this issue.

Are you loading your textures *onSurfaceCreated*? When you pause the application and resume, these textures need to be re-bound in OpenGL.

Also, are there any errors in the LogCat window if you are using Eclipse?

One thing you may want to do is enable OpenGL debug flags for testing. You can find information on this here:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/glsurfaceview.html